# How to organize CakePHP 3 Cells

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0, cells

I am creating an application with some pages that contains many charts etc. that are realized with CakePHP Cells to be very flexible.

However, the app will have around 100 Cells, which makes the folder structure very unorganized.

The only way I found in the Book is by using Cells from Plugins, but I don't really want to create a plugin for each category of Cells.

Does anybody know if it is somehow possible to put Cells in subfolders or something like that?

Thank You!

Comment: I think you can pass a FQN as the cell name, but I can't test it right now, so I'm not posting this as an answer. If it works, then you'll probably receive generic errors instead of `MissingCellException` exceptions in case the class doesn't exist. Another option might be `class_alias()` or overriding/reimplementing `CellTrait::cell()`.